# What is the easiest way to generate a pseudo-random number in C for cryptographic purpose?

Tags: c, random, cryptography

I need to generate random numbers for a student homework in cryptography.

At first I wanted to use

```
srand(time(NULL));
int r = rand();
```

But I read that shouldn't use it for cryptography.
I'd like if possible to **not** write my own pseudo-random number generator.

What is the fastest/easiest way to generate pseudo-random numbers in C for cryptographic purposes?

I'm on Linux and I don't mind if the answer isn't cross-platform.

Comment: Read from /dev/urandom

Comment: This is a trick question. There are easy ways and there are good ways but there no good easy ways. A cryptographic RNG is __hard__.

Comment: Unless there are demands being made on your solution that you've not mentioned, using `/dev/random` is likely to be good enough for student homework, whereas using `srand(time)` (and, indeed, `rand()`) is not.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler Please write that as an answer so that the current only “answer” does not get accepted through unfamiliarity with StackOverflow.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler Bad idea, you should not be using `/dev/random` directly if you only want pseudo random numbers. `/dev/random` provides entropy gathered by the system to feed other PRNG's, it is not a good idea for a application to use it directly (as it may block and therefore stall not just your application but others as well). Use `/dev/urandom` instead or use a well seeded PRNG within a cryptographic library.

Comment: @david.pfx PRNG methods are well known. Testing the implementation is very tricky however and getting enough entropy can be tricky as well, especially without OS support.

Comment: @owlstead: Agreed, but a quick answer for a student project that will meet cryptographic standards? What do you choose? Why?

Comment: `/dev/urandom` can be used directly by implementations instead. It won't block and will not deplete `/dev/random` so easily. For the rest, see my answer,

Comment: On Linux, `/dev/random` is basically intended for seed material, while `/dev/urandom` is a ready-to-use PRNG. On other platforms (say, FreeBSD or OS X), they are the same (one is simply symlinked to the other).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no cross-platform solution. On Linux, read from [`/dev/urandom`](http://linux.die.net/man/4/random) (with [`fread`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/fread), or with [`read`](http://linux.die.net/man/2/read) if you have a taste for complexity). The bytes read from `/dev/urandom` are suitable for cryptographic use except from a freshly-started embedded system or server lacking entropy.

The documentation is overly conservative (stemming from a theoretical notion of security where the attacker has infinite computation power rather than merely the use of all the computers int he world); in most situations, [it is perfectly fine to use `/dev/urandom` to generate cryptographic keys](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/3936/is-a-rand-from-dev-urandom-secure-for-a-login-key).

If you need to generate a lot of random bytes, you may want to implement a [pseudo-random number generator](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pseudorandom_number_generator) inside your code, and use `/dev/urandom` only to seed it with entropy. If you're just generating a few keys and similar small amounts of material, or if you need to generate a lot of random numbers but the speed of `/dev/urandom` isn't a bottleneck, or if this is a school exercise and implementing a PRNG is not the point of the exercise, then just reading from `/dev/urandom` is fine.

Answer (score 2):

Only having a Pseudo Random Number Generator is not enough. You need to seed it with enough entropy to start it up. You do this by setting a seed generally retrieved from one of the operating system calls. Which one you should use depends on the method that you use it. You can mix in seed later if you want even higher quality random numbers.

For Linux systems: `/dev/random` returns the most entropy, `/dev/urandom` is itself a seeded PRNG and may be used directly by applications. `/dev/random` however blocks if not enough entropy is available, I would advice `/dev/urandom` for most purposes. Reading too much from `/dev/random/` can bring down an entire machine as anything that requests entropy from it may stall. On other operating systems both `/dev/random` `/dev/urandom` simply link to a seeded PRNG.

For Windows take a look at [this article on MSDN](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/michael_howard/archive/2005/01/14/353379.aspx).

Comment: Added another answer, I read that you wanted to program your own PRNG, apologies. Removed Java SHA1PRNG sample code. Rest of answer is still valid, although I would recommend OpenSSL for as an API instead.

Comment: I've deleted my other post because of the continuing problems with OpenSSL.